# Compliación:Locale must be of the form - Error when publishing asp.net core web app to IIS or Azure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm going crazy with this error mainly because I have no idea what, or who is generating it. When I try to publish to azure or to IIS, in the publish started part the publish option breaks with error:

```
tsc(0,0): Error TS6048: Compilación:Locale must be of the form <language> or <language>-<territory>. For example 'en' or 'ja-jp'
```

The application has two simple localisations 'es-MX' and 'en-US' and when I publish locally everything runs normally and I get an publish output, but in this case the locale 'es-ES' is used. I honestly don't know where to start debugging or changing configurations so this can work.

What I'm thinking is to remove localization, but that could take an amount of time, also to simple remove js libraries. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the [similar issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16492) on the github, it seems that it is an issue of visual studio 2017. And there is a work around, please have a try.

> As a workaround, set the PreferedUILang in your project to a different language, e.g. en-us

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreferredUILang>en-us</PreferredUILang>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks. What I don't understand is why is my VS compiling in spanish. I mean all my dev environment is in english. I suspect a problem from more integration across services in Microsoft.